# Remove TableCell from each TableRow c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have used C# Table to display HTML Table in aspx page. I want to remove column from that Table.

```
DataTable getTxnOutput = // Get DataTable by Calling Stored Procedure;
Table txnOutputs = Generix.convertDataTable2HTMLTable(getTxnOutput);

foreach (TableRow trOutput in txnOutputs.Rows)
{
    if (trOutput.TableSection == TableRowSection.TableBody)
    {
    /*  Here i am doing some operation using column which i want to delete afterwards           */      
    txnOutputs.Rows[0].Cells.Remove(trOutput.Cells[6]); //Now delete that column
    }
}
Page.Controls.Add(txnOutputs);
```

But above code will delete cell only in first row.
How can I delete in every row without using further more loops.

**I found Solution but can i incorporate same in above loop... I just want to avoid two loops..**

```
for (int k = 0; k < txnOutputs.Rows.Count; k++)
   {
   txnOutputs.Rows[k].Cells.Remove(txnOutputs.Rows[k].Cells[6]);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this line

`txnOutputs.Rows[0].Cells.Remove(trOutput.Cells[6]);`

be

`trOutput.Cells.Remove(trOutput.Cells[6]);`?

Comment: No..It gives error `'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table' could be found`

Comment: @SagarDumbre: How is that possible considering that `trOutput` is of type `TableRow`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include the forloop inside if, and use a Variable something like viewstate[X]=1 inside if statement, and check

```
if(viewstate[X]==1)
{
  // logic here
}  
viewstate[X]=0;
```

run for loop
after end of For loop set `viewstate[X]=0`

so that you can run for loop only once else it will loop through every row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    DataTable getTxnOutput = // Get DataTable by Calling Stored Procedure;
    Table txnOutputs = Generix.convertDataTable2HTMLTable(getTxnOutput);
    int i = 0;
    foreach (TableRow trOutput in txnOutputs.Rows)
    {
        if (trOutput.TableSection == TableRowSection.TableBody)
        {
        /*  Here i am doing some operation using column which i want to delete afterwards           */      
         txnOutputs.Rows[i].Cells.Remove(trOutput.Cells[6]); //Now delete that column
        }
        i++;
    }
    Page.Controls.Add(txnOutputs);
```